# How do I fix the 'Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'' problem in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to start my Xcode and I receive a warning that says: '“Project” is currently in conflict. Do you want to abort the current operation?' I press abort and I get this error:

> Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.'

I have been unable to pull from repositories and unable to checkout other branches. I tried to fix this by using the terminal but it did not work.

Comment: Can you please add more details what have you tried on terminal ? If you do a git status, what do you get ? I mean you can use `git reset --hard` command to reset the HEAD., if changes to your project are not required.

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same message during I wanted to abort an ongoing merge(messed up something during merge conflicts). I assume that XCode tried to refresh your branch automatically or something in that direction.

So, I tried:

```
git merge --abort
```

which gave me the same error message:

```
error: Entry 'some/package/Broken.java' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

I openend 'git gui' and unstaged the automatic staged classes. After this an abort worked with:

```
git merge --abort
```

This was done on git bash console.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove index and reset as suggested here:**

```
rm .git/index
git reset
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like more of a git conflict issue. You can undo a git merge with conflicts doing

```sh
git merge --abort
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I ended up deleting my project and cloning from a repository I’m working on. Fixed the issue. If the error occurs again I’ll try what you said.

Comment: That brute force always work but should be avoided! This statement does nothing but to abort the merge. You can do it if you have a lots of conflicts that aren’t possible to resolve manually e.g. Pod folder conflicts.